# Pythonsetuptools pkg_resources pip wheel failed with error code 1 [Error]

Tags: python, ubuntu, virtualenv, ubuntu-16.04

I got the following error while creating virtual environment on ubuntu 16.04.

```
OSError: Command /home/ubuntu/.virtua...skdeploy/bin/python2 - setuptools pkg_resources pip wheel failed with error code 1
```

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Add the following **locale variables**.

**`export LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"`**

**`export LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"`**

and run `virtualenv` command again

Comment: Could you please explain how this helps resolve this issue? I went over documentation here - https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xbd/envvar.html   . It suggests that LC_ALL, LC_TYPE got to do with locale language. How does it help with this specific issue?

Answer (score 4):

First try this 
1)

```
`sudo apt-get install python-setuptools`
```

and

2)

```
export LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"

export LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
```

Comment: python-setuptools